# Show / Hide toggle text based on :target (No JS)

Tags: css

What I'm trying to create is a toggle that's workable without using JavaScript or jQuery. The main issue that I'm having is with getting the toggle text to switch from Open to Close when :target is applied on the #menu selector. The navigation is collapsed by default and is opened by #menu toggle.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="site-nav" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="site-nav__toggle">
  <a class="site-nav__toggle--open" href="#menu">Open</a>
  <a class="site-nav__toggle--close" href="">Close</a>
</section>
```

**CSS via SCSS**

```
.site-nav {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;

  &:target {
    height: 100%;
      min-height: 170px;
    transition: height .25s ease, min-height .25s ease;
  }
}

.site-nav__toggle--open > .site-nav:target,
.site-nav__toggle--close > .site-nav {
  display: none;
}

.site-nav__toggle--close > .site-nav:target,
.site-nav__toggle--open > .site-nav {
  display: inline;
}
```

The main problem I have is that the text is not switching on the target states. Maybe a 2nd pair of eyes would help and spot the obvious if I've missed anything in this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From W3C:

> div > p
>
> Selects all P elements where the parent is a DIV element
>
> div + p
>
> Selects all P elements that are placed immediately after DIV elements

I think your selectors should look like

```
.site-nav:target + .site-nav__toggle .site-nav__toggle--open,
.site-nav + .site-nav__toggle .site-nav__toggle--close {
  display: none;
}

.site-nav:target + .site-nav__toggle .site-nav__toggle--close,
.site-nav + .site-nav__toggle .site-nav__toggle--open {
  display: inline;
}
```

Check this codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/goAIu

Best,
Marek

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, and this is exactly why a 2nd pair of eyes helped!